# Pandas: Return first column number that matches a condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this

```
    a     b     c     d
0  0.6  -0.4   0.2   0.7
1  0.8   0.2  -0.2   0.3
2 -0.1   0.5   0.5  -0.4
3  0.8  -0.6  -0.7  -0.2
```

And I wish to create column 'e' such that it displays the column number of the first instance in each row where the value is less than 0

So the goal result will look like this

```
    a     b     c     d    e
0  0.6  -0.4   0.2   0.7   2
1  0.8   0.2  -0.2   0.3   3
2 -0.1   0.5   0.5  -0.4   1
3  0.8  -0.6  -0.7  -0.2   2
```

I can do this in Excel using a MATCH(True) type function but am struggling to make progress in Pandas.

Thanks for any help

Comment: What specifically is the issue? Have you tried anything, done any research? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1):

You can use `np.argmax`:

```
# where the values are less than 0
a = df.values < 0

# if the row is all non-negative, return 0
df['e'] = np.where(a.any(1), np.argmax(a,axis=1)+1, 0)
```

Output:

```
     a    b    c    d  e
0  0.6 -0.4  0.2  0.7  2
1  0.8  0.2 -0.2  0.3  3
2 -0.1  0.5  0.5 -0.4  1
3  0.8 -0.6 -0.7 -0.2  2
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like `idxmin` with `np.sin`

```
import numpy as np 
df['e']=df.columns.get_indexer(np.sign(df).idxmin(1))+1
df
     a    b    c    d  e
0  0.6 -0.4  0.2  0.7  2
1  0.8  0.2 -0.2  0.3  3
2 -0.1  0.5  0.5 -0.4  1
3  0.8 -0.6 -0.7 -0.2  2
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the first max, combined with [get indexer for](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_indexer_for.html) to get the column numbers:

```
    df["e"] = df.columns.get_indexer_for(df.lt(0, axis=1).idxmax(axis=1).array) + 1
    df


     a  b       c    d      e
0   0.6  -0.4   0.2  0.7    2
1   0.8   0.2  -0.2  0.3    3
2  -0.1   0.5   0.5  -0.4   1
3   0.8  -0.6  -0.7 -0.2    2
```